# Retrieve a value of a row when clicked hyperlink field of that row in a gridview in asp.net using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, hyperlink

I'm making a tour and travel website. But I'm stuck with a problem. I have a `DropDownList` and below it a `GridView`. As soon as I select a value in the `DropDownList`, the respective values in the `GridView` shows up. I have converted a column of a `GridView` into `HyperLink` in the code behind file. Each `HyperLink` navigate to a different url.

Markup page:

Select destination:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <asp:ListItem>Make a selection</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="1">jaipur</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="2">manali</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <br />
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="package_id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound1" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged1" AutoGenerateSelectButton="false">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Title_of_package" HeaderText="Title_of_package" SortExpression="Title_of_package" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="No_of_Days" HeaderText="No_of_Days" SortExpression="No_of_Days" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Details" HeaderText="Details" SortExpression="Details" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="package_id" HeaderText="package_id" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="package_id" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:registrationConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Title_of_package], [No_of_Days], [Details], [package_id] FROM [User_choice] WHERE ([Id_of_place] = @Id_of_place)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="Id_of_place" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Code behind file in C#:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound1(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            // Get the value in the hyperlink column.
            string HyperLinkValue = e.Row.Cells[2].Text;

            if (e.Row.Cells[3].Text == "100")
            {    
                HyperLink myLink = new HyperLink();
                myLink.NavigateUrl = "~/afterlogin/ChokiDhaniVisit.aspx";
                myLink.Text = HyperLinkValue;
                // then add the control to the cell.
                e.Row.Cells[2].Controls.Add(myLink);
            }    

            if (e.Row.Cells[3].Text == "101")
            {    
                HyperLink myLink = new HyperLink();
                myLink.NavigateUrl = "~/Manali.aspx";
                myLink.Text = HyperLinkValue;
                // then add the control to the cell.
                e.Row.Cells[2].Controls.Add(myLink);
            }
        }
    }
```

Now I want as soon as user click on the `HyperLink` column of a row its Title_of_package to get stored in a label. I have tried:

```
 protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Label11.Text = ((HyperLink)GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Controls[0]).Text;
        Label11.Text = Session["destype"].ToString();

    }
```

But it is showing up error. I am a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following adding this to `GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged`

```
GridViewRow row = GridView1.SelectedRow;
HyperLink hyperLink = ((HyperLink)row.FindControl["hyperlinkname"]);

Label1.Text = hyperLink.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

you`r nearly there but the session is used as follows

```
Session["desType"] = ((HyperLink)GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Controls[0]).Text;
```

and you get it like

```
Label1.Text = Session["desType"].toString();
```